# What happens when python's reload() does not find the module file?

Tags: python, reload

I generate code at runtime for my application and therefore I need to reload some of my modules so as not to re-launch.

My generated package may contain new files or have files deleted (just to be sure, all the .pyc are deleted each time code is generated).

I do something like this:

```
for name, module in sys.modules.iteritems():
    if name.startswith('my.dynamic.package.') and module is not None:
    try:    
        reload(module)
    except ImportError:
        pass
```

So what if some of my modules was deleted? I will get the ImportError as expected, but is my module removed from runtime?

Answer (score 1):

No, `reload` never deletes the module object. It simply modifies the module object in-place. So, in case the reload fails the old bindings still remain intact.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload

```
#so.py
i = 0
lis = [1,2,3]
dic = {"a":1, "b":2}
```

Now let's import this module:

```
>>> import so
>>> x = so.lis[0]  
>>> so.lis[0]=0            #modify so.lis
>>> so.dic["a"] = so.lis   #modify so.dic
>>> !rm -r  so.py so.pyc   #delete both so.py and so.pyc 
>>> try:                   #try reloading
...     reload(so)
... except ImportError:
...     pass
... 
>>> so.lis                 #previous binding are still intact
[0, 2, 3]
>>> x
1
>>> so.dic
{'a': [0, 2, 3], 'b': 2}
```

Now instead of deleting we'll try to modify the module:

```
#so.py
i = 0
lis = [1,2,3,4]
dic = {"a":1, "b":2}
```

Now import it:

```
>>> import so
>>> lis = so.lis     #add a new reference to it
>>> so.lis[0] = 0    #modify so.lis
>>> so.i
0
```

Now modify so.py to:

```
#so.py
i = 0
lis = [1,2,3]       #updated lis
dic = {"a":1, "b":2}
```

Now `reload()`:

```
>>> reload(so)
<module 'so' from 'so.py'>

>>> so.lis       #got updated
[1, 2, 3]
>>> lis          #old so.lis object is still in memory as it's reference count is not 0
[0, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

--**EDIT**: Whoops Ashwini Chaudhary was quicker than I was :)

Should have made a little more research before posting this.

I will answer my own question: hopefully, it might be interesting for some of you.

Imagine I have already imported my module once:

```
import plop
```

If `plop.py` and `plop.pyc` are deleted:

```
>>> reload(plop)
ImportError: no module named plop
```

But beware! The module is not deleted from the modules dict.

```
>>> print repr(sys.modules['plop'])
<module 'plop' from plop.py>
```

However I can remove it manually

```
>>> del sys.modules['plop']
>>> import plop
ImportError: no module named plop
```

*In this case of import error*: wherever I would already have imported the module, the code is still bound to the local variable name chosen on import time -typically the module name-. The module still exists in my runtime.

So I did just a little more experiments.

If somewhere in my code I happened to have imported a *function* from my module, whether the reload works or not, I would still have *a reference to the old function*.

```
>>> from plop import somefunc
>>> somefunc()
i am the first version!
>>> # code is regenerated
>>> reload(plop)
>>> # should print "i am the second version!"
>>> somefunc()
i am the first version!
```

If I had used `plop.somefunc()` instead, I would have been up-to-date, for the case when the reload works.

My conclusion is : when I reload modules, I should always be careful and **re-import** whatever I need to use, should it be module or module field. And in case of failure to reload, I should clean up the sys.modules dict.